# How can create a regular expression for this URL?

Tags: javascript

I'm not good with RegEx and I would like have a RegEx for next URL scheme.

Can you help me to create a regular expression for that URL?

```
https://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf
```

And if possible, show me one page to learn and understand it.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: I solved with this regex. let expression = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*){fontstack}\/{range}.pbf/gi;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best page I use to explain RegEx is https://regex101.com/.

In case your characters are all word characters, you can just use:

```
https://fonts/mapbox/(\w+)/(\w+).pbf
```

In the first group you will have "fontstack" and in the second you will have "range".

If you want to include a bit more of possible characters, maybe:

```
https://fonts/mapbox/([^\s\/])/([^\s\/]).pbf
```

You can see extensive explanations to both introducing them on the page I provided at the start.

Comment: thanks :D
the idea is 'https://' required + [n * anything text with / ] + \.[a-z]{2,6} + [n * anything text with / ] + '{fontstack]/{range}.pbf